# android:notification

Tags: android-notifications

I have to make appicon notification as done in iphone type appicon notification.I have to implement notification like a small image showing some data or just a plain image over my app icon programmatically in android.So, far i have tried implementing by notification manager but i am not able to implement any notification image over my app icon.Please suggest me some possible ways of showing notification over app icon in android.For reference please provide the source code of SMS Unread Count apk.